# Mpeg-dash playback

Tags: http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, ott

I've been trying to figure out how to playback an mpeg-dash xml file directly in chrome (Version 30.0.1599.69 m) with the html5 video element. Something like

the mpd file has been created with mp4box and the video codec is MP4.

But this is obviously not the correct method. I'm aware of the "dash.js" project - but why cant the browser handle all the details, when they've added support for mpeg-dash playback?

Is there any way to play an mpeg-dash without any use of javascript?

Is there an open source flash player for mpeg-dash? (with support for live streams, file streams, multiple audio tracks and sub titling)

We are planning a project for OTT streaming of live tv and VOD and would prefere to use MPEG-dash, but it looks like its not a complete design yet, and we are also thinking of using HLS with some kind of flash player for browsers without HLS support. Is HLS an better choise, even its not an ISO standard?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe, just using plain html5 to play a video, only supports progressive download (not streaming).  With streaming/adaptive streaming  you will need some kind of player like the one suggested above.  Note that there is also a *free mpeg-dash player*, [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki), which I had working in an hour.  But with mpeg-dash, only the latest browsers and devices support it.  It's gaining in popularity but as you say, support is still limited.  You are on the right track with HLS.  I had to implement a solution recently that targeted the largest audience (old and new browsers and devices) and I ended up with JWPlayer and HLS V3. HLS is only second to flash as far as the widest support and it has the advantage of working well with the latest tech as well.  MPEG-DASH is the future.  Flash is the past.  **HLS V3 is the now**.

One note, Android before 4.x didn't support HLS but Android devices tend to get push updates so my above answer assumes most Android users are running newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are planning an App, you may use the open source library libdash:  http://www.bitmovin.net/libdash

As far as I know, they also have Flash and Java-based Versions of http://www.bitmovin.net/bitdash.html

Answer (score 1):

Wowza now supports MPEG-DASH nDVR for live streaming and has a player. Users can play or pause the live stream, rewind it to a previously recorded point, or resume viewing at the current live point.

Docs to do this can be found here:

https://www.wowza.com/docs/wowza-ndvr-quick-start-guide

[I work for Wowza.]